# Import Activity from a directory inside the Import directory

Tags: marketing-cloud

Triggered Automations recommends Importing from a directory besides the default Import directory. I created a sub folder called 'TriggeredAutomations'. How do I set-up the Import to use this directory? Do I have to create a new File Location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have read the documentation completely.

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/triggered_automations/#FTPTAutomationScenario